# Weird blue underline on svg hover

Tags: css, svg

I have svg for social media icon and everytime I hover on it, it creates this blue underline and nothing seems to take it off. How can I remove it?

[image]

Here's how I include it.

```
<a class="footer-socialmedia-icons" style="padding-right:0.5rem;" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com">
    <img width="35px" height="35px" src="/files/IMG/facebook.svg" alt="facebook logo" class="">
</a>
```

EDIT:
here's the svg:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 41.1 (35376) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>facebook</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="facebook" fill="#DBC5DA">
            <path d="M24.826,0 C11.137,0 0,11.137 0,24.826 C0,38.514 11.137,49.652 24.826,49.652 C38.514,49.652 49.652,38.514 49.652,24.826 C49.652,11.137 38.516,0 24.826,0 Z M31,25.7 L26.961,25.7 L26.961,40.096 L20.976,40.096 L20.976,25.7 L18.131,25.7 L18.131,20.612 L20.976,20.612 L20.976,17.321 C20.976,14.964 22.096,11.281 27.016,11.281 L31.451,11.298 L31.451,16.237 L28.232,16.237 C27.708,16.237 26.963,16.499 26.963,17.623 L26.963,20.613 L31.523,20.613 L31,25.7 Z" id="Shape"></path>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

### EDIT

As it turns out, the blue line is underneath all  tags. Tried `text-decoration:none` on  but it doesn't do a thing.

Comment: Please include relevant CSS rules and perhaps the SVG as well.

Comment: @josephting at the moment there are no css rules besides the inline styling that is added (padding-right:0.5rem;) Also how can I add the file?

Comment: You should be able to open a SVG file using any text editor. Add the content of the file in your post.

Comment: Is this browser specific or are you getting it in all browsers?

Comment: @VivekAthalye all browsers

Comment: Have you tried `a:hover{text-decoration: none;}`

Comment: @Justinas literally tried everything

Comment: @raqulka Can you provide SO Snippet with reproduced issue?

Comment: Not able to reproduce your issue in Chrome / FF. Try accessing this and see if you get the underline: (I've used the same SVG and html that you have shared) http://plnkr.co/edit/3AWVghhiVXgwTpLZZMno?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers add a border to images in `a` elements to show them as clickable links.

If you don't want that, add

```css
a img {border:none}
```

to your CSS.
This is not connected to SVG by the way; it happens on all images inside links.

Comment: Trying it now. Second.

Comment: Okay after adding that,  clearing all cache, restarting wamp and restarting my computer the border is gone. EDIT: I removed the rule and the border is gone as well. Must have been some kind of cache issue. Thanks, but I will keep that rule memorized for the future reference.